# No Outline while Dragging Object

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I just started getting into adobe illustrator again and upon install, I noticed that, while dragging/transforming objects, I don't seem to get the preview outline that looks similar to [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/user-guide.html/illustrator/using/moving-aligning-distributing-objects.ug.html). Is there a setting I don't know about?

Comment: I know of no setting which would disable the outline preview when dragging objects. Im afraid this is more technical support which is off-topic and I think you'll need to ask Adobe. Or, your issue is *specifically* related to what you are dragging. If you draw a simple rectangle and drag it, you don't get a blue outline as you drag?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I spent a number of hours trying to find a solution but nothing yet.

Comment: Well I can't replicate the problem here. Sorry, but I think you need to ask Adobe. The ONLY thing I can think of is to try switching to the CPU preview (View menu) --- perhaps your GPU isn't robust enough to handle the preview.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you! I was scouring preferences for literal hours, but that seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Glad that worked or you -- but that does mean the video card in the computer you are using is fairly underpowered by todays's standards.

Comment: @Scott no it just means he has newest version of AI installed. They actually changed code so that objects draw as fully rendered when dragging. I was quite angry at adobe untill i found the option as i primarily work on finding intersections and accurate intersections, and the feature makes certain tasks easier.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this change was added in last adobe update, indeed the old preview is better for many workflows. You can toggle between this on and off under

**Preferences → Perfomance → Real time Editing**

Put a chakmark on the option for it to work the way you ask.

The option *only applies to GPU accelerated drawing* so turning to cpu rendering also does the trick. But by checking this option it revets to the old editing style also in GPU editing looks the same as CPU editing.

Comment: .. interesting....